# Create zip of folder with same name

Tags: bash, zip

I want to create zip of a folder from command-line. I can do something like
`zip -r folder.zip folder`. I want to give the zipped folder same name as the original folder. I can simulate this by writing a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
zip -r $1 $1
```

And then doing `./script folder`.

Is it possible to do this *without* writing any script?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is how you do it straight with the shell:

```
zip -r folder{.zip,}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can add a bash function that does this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
function fzip {
    zip -r $1 $1
}
```

Then in the shell you can do:

```
user@host:~$ fzip my_folder
# creates my_folder.zip
```

Comment: A bash function IS a script