# `zip` works in shell but not in Python script

Tags: command-line, bash, python, scripts, zip

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/525489/380067) post I'm calling the `zip` command using `os.system()` in Python.

At the command line it works:

```
zip -r /Backups/backups/20152011-120209{.zip,}
```

When I call this from a Python script (`PATH` is "/Backups/backups/20152011-120209")

```py
os.system("zip -r " + PATH + "{.zip,}")
```

It throws:

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (/Backups/backups/20152011-122909{.zip,})
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want to zip a directory (including its content) to a zip file with the same name at the same place (a script dumps my MySQL databases to *.sql files and I want to zip the files after that).

Comment: Not at home right now, but using `os.system` *at all* is a really bad idea. Outdated and deprecated. Use `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen() ` intead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting to the problem, I'll quote Jacob Vlijm's comment under this answer (thanks for the comment and for the link):

> [...] using os.system at all is a really bad idea. Outdated and deprecated. Use subprocess.call() or subprocess.Popen() intead.

[Here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-July/102369.html)'s the first (or one of the first) deprecation proposal, dated back to *2010*.

So you should really use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `os.system()`.

---

When you run `os.system()` the command is executed in Dash (`/bin/sh`), while when you run the command in a terminal the command is executed in Bash (`/bin/bash`);

Dash doesn't support brace expansion and interprets `{.zip,}` literally;

Run the command in Bash: change

```py
os.system("zip -r " + PATH + "{.zip}")
```

to

```py
os.system("bash -c 'zip -r " + PATH + "{.zip,}'")
```

Or anyway as Darael suggests FWIW passing `/Backups/backups/20152011-120209{.zip,}` to expand `/Backups/backups/20152011-120209` to `/Backups/backups/20152011-120209.zip` and `/Backups/backups/20152011-120209` you might as well just pass the paths directly avoiding to spawn another shell:

```py
os.system("zip -r " + PATH + ".zip " + PATH)
```

Comment: Thank you kos for your comment. Unfortunately it was mistyped in my question - in my script there was an "," at the end. I corrected my original question. So, you aure right, but it does not solve my problem :(

Comment: @Benninger Maybe you mistyped again, but the comma goes *before the closing brace*, here's what you just posted: `os.system("zip -r " + PATH + "{.zip},")`.

Comment: Yes I mistyped it again, sorry for that. In my script os.system("zip -r " + PATH + "{.zip,}") is used and it shows still  zip error: Nothing to do! (/Backups/backups/20152011-122909{.zip,})

Comment: The curly brackets are a bash feature. I'm guessing that python's os.system() either bypasses shells entirely or uses a shell (probably `/bin/sh`, which in Ubuntu is `dash`, which I think fits) that doesn't support the syntax. Whichever is the case, the solution is to expand in your python script to `os.system("zip -r "+PATH+".zip "+PATH")`

Comment: @Darael That's absolutely correct, I just figured that out and updated the answer.

Comment: @Benninger See the updated answer.

Comment: @kos Thank you for your input - it is absolutely correct and working now!

Comment: @Darael Thank you for your input - it is absolutely correct and working now!

Comment: @Darael Thanks for the edit, I didn't notice I inverted the paths.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Not a pythonista myself, I didn't know about that. I take it for granted since *you* say it :). Can I quote your comment within the answer?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Done, thanks for the comment and for the link :)