# Zip archive name using on the first zipfile's name

Tags: zip

I want to create the backup of the Wordpress website in a directory `example.com`. The output file should be in the following format:

```
YmDHM_example.com.zip
```

Using the current date and time, it would be: `202003211045_example.com.zip`.

So far I got to this point:

```
$ zip -r "$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")_example.com.zip" example.com
```

But would like the `example.com` part to be also created "dynamically". I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/525489/494526) answer, but it doesn't mention how to include the date in the output file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using find to filter and format output for zip command:

```bsh
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'example.com' \
  -printf %f\\0 | xargs -0 -I {} zip -r $(date -d now +%Y%m%d%H%M)_{}.zip {}
```